# PostgreSQL: Return function if table exists else 0 within a view

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having trouble getting PostgreSQL to recognize the matches table is empty and thus should output 0 for the wins and matches columns within the view below. Instead, I keep getting an empty view. When I should be getting a "player id","player id", 0, 0 for each row. What could be the problem?

```
CREATE VIEW player_standings AS
SELECT 
    players.id,
    players.name,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM matches) THEN COUNT(matches.winner) ELSE 0 END AS wins,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM matches) THEN COUNT(matches.winner) + COUNT(matches.loser) ELSE 0 END AS matches
FROM players
INNER JOIN matches
    ON players.id = matches.winner
GROUP BY players.id
ORDER BY
    wins DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You do not need `case` because `count(null)` gives 0.
2. You should `left join` matches in case there no matches for a given player.
3. You should `join` matches two times to get number of wins and loses.

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW player_standings AS
SELECT 
    p.id,
    p.name,
    COUNT(m1.winner) AS wins,
    COUNT(m1.winner) + COUNT(m2.loser) AS matches
FROM players p
LEFT JOIN matches m1
    ON p.id = m1.winner
LEFT JOIN matches m2
    ON p.id = m2.loser
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
ORDER BY
    wins DESC;
```